# Webdriver click second element in list

Tags: selenium

The page I'm testing has 2 elements with the same name and I need to click the second Element.
I can get the elements by using:

```
driver.findElements(By.linkText("Services"));
```

But I don't know how to `click` on the second element.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:
1) Using xpath, try in following manner.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("('xpath of the link')[2]"));//If you had given html, I could have added exact xpath.
```

2) Using findElements() you can try following:

```
List<WebElement> li = driver.findElements(By.linkText("Services"));;
li.get(1).click();//If there are only two such element, here 1 is index of 2nd element in list returned.
```

Hope you get the idea. :)

Comment: Option two works! I was on the right path, just doing it incorrectly. Thanks!

Comment: Most welcome. Do accept the answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

Or for short you can do

```
driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("drop"))[1].Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you`re using python, you can try this way:

```
li = driver.findElements(By.linkText("Services"))[index].click()
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation. Check this: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)